# Blender 2.8, missing keymap settings

Tags: interface, customization

after installation of blender 2.8 I cannot click on anything in the 3D view and the outliner tree structure. Besides all shortkeys are not working at all.

In the Settings of blender 2.8, the whole Keymap tab is empty. I reinstalled it and even tried to use the non install version - this problem still remain... (OS clean Windows 10 x64)

Any ideas :D ?
[image]

Comment: have you got that latest release from https://www.blender.org/download/ ? Can you try the .ZIP version and run it from a separate extracted folder?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but yeah.. as I wrote above - I tried the zip version too (yes I have used a different directory several times. I even deleted all %appdata% files from blender). And yes, I use Blender 2.8 released version. -Belia

Comment: Please don't use the answer section to provide more details. If you have further info edit your original question instead

Comment: try File/Defaults/Load Factory Settings. Also try launching from the command line to see if any errors are reported.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.
I discovered I had two versions of python installed and after deleting the oldest version, my issues were resolved. Do the same and hopefully it works.

To check if you have multiple versions of python installed you can go to the command prompt window and enter **C:\Users\YourUserName>py -0** and it should list all your current installs.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from this as well. Here is what fixed it for me.

To fix this go to C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Roaming and then Delete the Blender Foundation folder. Restart Blender. When you start blender again you will be able to use blender again.